# Rest Web Service - Object Mapper

Tags: java, json, rest, webservice-client

I am working on Rest based application where I am creating the rest client. The problem is while sending the post request the object is expected to be JSON.

```
Class User{ String first_Name; String last_Name; //getters & setters }

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter(); String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

The above code returns with correct JSON format, however the underscore of the class attributes are getting eliminated. Eg. I am expected the result to be like

`{"first_Name":"Joseph","last_Name":"Thomas"}`

but the actual result is

```
{"firstName":"Joseph","lastName":"Thomas"}.
```

Can someone help me how to get the json with underscore. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Also note that a local variable with the following naming convention "first_Name" is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@JsonProperty()` in your User class: Example:

```
@JsonProperty("first_Name")
String first_Name; 
@JsonProperty("last_Name")
String first_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your fields with `@JsonProperty`, e.g.

```
@JsonProperty("first_Name")
private String firstName;
```

Comment: Thanks Robby & Codeguy, I have already tried with @JsonProperty, still the result were the same, no underscore :(

Comment: What if you put the annotation on your getter? And, is your field `private`?